# What is the difference between Set, and Class in object oriented languages?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computer-algebra-systems

What is the difference between Set in set theory, and Class in object oriented languages?

Comment: Set theory specifies properties and operations which ought to be satisfied by entities which it calls Sets. Therefore Sets is, in computer science, a type. One can say that each set is an object of type Set. A class is an specification of the implementation of objects of a certain type. A class determines a type (but not the other way around). Perhaps you would like to consider the set all objects that a class can create, but notice that that set and the class are not the same thing. Having the collection of all objects doesn't determine the implementation.

Comment: You might get a better answer on StackOverflow. Sets are fairly simple (unless you're a set theorist), so there will be plenty of people on SO who understand both sets and classes. Around here, there are lots of people who know about sets, but not so many who can clearly explain programming concepts.

Answer (score 3):

There are debates about the definition, but, for elementary work, a set is just a collection of things, which are called its "members". So $\{3, \pi, \text{Jupiter}\}$ is a set whose members are two numbers and a planet. The members of a set do not all have to be the same kinds of things, and they do not need to have any relationship to each other.

In object-oriented programming, a class provides a "blueprint" or "template" for objects of a **similar type**, that have some **common** set of properties and methods. Specific objects that follow the blueprint are called "instances" of the class.

In programming, the closest thing to a set is a C# ArrayList or a Python tuple. These are both collections whose members can be anything you like. For example

```
ArrayList a = { 3, System.Math.Pi, "hello" };
```

is a perfectly legal definition of an ArrayList whose members are two numbers and a string.

But sets and ArrayList-like collections still have some large differences. ArrayLists are finite, and sets are often infinite. Also, the elements of an ArrayList have a specific order, and elements of a set do not. In common programming languages, I can't think of a data structure that represents an unordered collection.

In short, sets and classes have very little in common, so asking how they are different is a somewhat odd question.

Comment: A class in object oriented programming is not a collection of objects.

Comment: Python has the `set` type.

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented programming often needs some kind of abstraction since every time you create a Class you are defining some type of real or abstract object that has inner properties (attributes) and operations that it can perform (methods).

Thus a Set is a collection of single type objects (remember that inheritance/polymorphism will point to a single object at last) that can perform some operation in each of these objects. The default Sets in any programming language will give you some default methods to sort the collection by a default or customized comparation and other general methods some times not useful for your logic.

But you, as a programmer, can define complex methods to integrate to those Sets, therefore extending the functionality to your abstract design. This is when programming and mathematics come together to the same point.

You can define a Set with some fixed properties and operations that performs these in order to calculate whatever you want, i.e: Sets of matrices under addition and multiplication where each matrix has methods of inverting themselves. Or Sets of polynomial equations that can perform GCD, composition and rooth finding algorithms on multiple polynomials. The idea behind this is to give the programmer the scheme to create whatever he wants to achieve by defining the same behaviour (properties) which he is working with.

Answer (score -1):

In set theory, there are things called equivalence relations which can be used to glob things that are alike into sets called equivalence classes. I think this is where the class idea comes from programming. The objects created by a class in programming all have the same structure and so in some sense they are equivalent!

A class in programming is a "program-code-template" so I don't know what type of "thing" a template even is. This question is way too hard.

Comment: Heuristically speaking, the axioms of any set theory is establishing the class "Set". There is no set of all sets so there can only be a logical blueprint for what they are. The use of class in computer science is mirroring this idea.